# Tagsoup and XOM on android

Tags: java, android, xom

Can i use `Tagsoup` and `XOM` on android 1.6 without any performance problems ?

Comment: Do you mean this? http://www.xom.nu/

Answer (score 1):

Performance considerations are unavoidable on a limited platform like a mobile phone. That said the Dalvik JVM in Android is highly optimised so any well performing library (and XOM is generally pretty good, I don't know too much and Tagsoup) will perform ok.

Your real performance problems here will stem from the structure and size of the XML documents you intend to process. XML processing is generally slow on any platform as it involves a lot of string parsing and manipulation by the XML parser. So on a limited platform use the smallest XML documents you can get away with. If you control the structure of the XML structure it in a way that you can get the information you need without have to repeatedly scan the entire document.